# LINQ return parent with subset of children based on grandchild criteria

Tags: c#, linq

I can't work out how accomplish this LINQ query.  I have a database structured like so:

```
User  ->  UserAccess  <-  Terminal  <-  Site
```

Terminals belong to sites, UserAccess specifies which users have access to which terminals.  For a given user, I would like to retrieve all available terminals *by site*.  Given `Site`s already maintain a collection of `Terminals`, this would be a `Site[]` but with only a subset of `Terminals` populated.

I started from (I think) the wrong end, and I am able to retrieve a list of `Sites`, and filter on the child `Terminals`:

```
using (MsSqlDataContextDataContext db = new MsSqlDataContextDataContext())
{
    // This is part of a WCF Data Service.  If I don't LoadWith I have lazy-loading problems
    DataLoadOptions options = new DataLoadOptions();
    options.LoadWith<site>(s => s.Terminals);

    // I found AssociateWith can filter on a child collection, but I can't work out
    // how to do the same for grand-child.
    options.AssociateWith<site>(s => s.Terminals.Where(t => t.Active));
    db.LoadOptions = options;

    return db.sites.Where(s => s.Active).ToArray();
}
```

But I can't filter the `Terminals` by their child collection `UserAccess`.

I decided to try again querying from the middle, and I think I'm getting close.  I can now retrieve a list of `Terminals` but I can't retrieve a list of `Sites`:

```
return db.UserAccess.Where(a => a.Username.Equals(username) && a.HasAccess ))
                    .Select(a => a.Terminal).ToArray();
```

I've tried adding `.GroupBy(t => t.Site)` but that creates an anonymous type, when I really want my existing type populated with these results.  Also WCF had conniptions when I tried to return `IGrouping<Site, Terminal>`.

I have the feeling that if I ever manage to work out a solution on my own it will be 11 chained commands, when there is a way to do it in 2, and it would make people wince to see it.

The answer to [Linq query to return grandparent, parent and grandchild based on a grandchild's property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708990/linq-query-to-return-grandparent-parent-and-grandchild-based-on-a-grandchilds) generates an anonymous type for each result, you get hundreds of Terminals each with it's individual site, no grouping.

The question [Linq query to return filtered data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28610673/linq-query-to-return-filtered-data) is what I'm looking to do, but (like him) I want to avoid having to iterate the data explicitly.

***Edit:*** An attempt to provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.  Unfortunately it's pretty horrible.  I'm trying to replicate the existing class structure I have, which are LINQ to SQL models.  It generates circular references (`Terminal` has a foreign key for `Site`, but `Site` has a collection of `Terminals`).

```
public void LinqQuery()
{
    Site s1 = new Site { SiteName = "Site 1", Terminals = new List<Terminal>() };
    Site s2 = new Site { SiteName = "Site 2", Terminals = new List<Terminal>() };

    Terminal t1 = new Terminal { TerminalName = "Terminal 1:1", site = s1, AccessList = new List<UserAccess>() };
    Terminal t2 = new Terminal { TerminalName = "Terminal 2:1", site = s1, AccessList = new List<UserAccess>() };
    s1.Terminals.Add(t1);
    s1.Terminals.Add(t2);

    Terminal t3 = new Terminal { TerminalName = "Terminal 3:2", site = s2, AccessList = new List<UserAccess>() };
    Terminal t4 = new Terminal { TerminalName = "Terminal 4:2", site = s2, AccessList = new List<UserAccess>() };
    s2.Terminals.Add(t3);
    s2.Terminals.Add(t4);

    User u1 = new User { Name = "Ian" };

    UserAccess ua1 = new UserAccess { user = u1, terminal = t1 };
    t1.AccessList.Add(ua1);

    UserAccess ua2 = new UserAccess { user = u1, terminal = t2 };
    t2.AccessList.Add(ua2);

    UserAccess ua3 = new UserAccess { user = u1, terminal = t4 };
    t4.AccessList.Add(ua3);

    Site[] allSites = {s1, s2};
    Terminal[] allTerminals = {t1, t2, t3, t4};
    UserAccess[] allUserAccess = {ua1, ua2, ua3};

    // This gives me a list of all terminals where user "Ian" has access (3 Terminals)
    var v = allUserAccess.Where(ua => ua.user.Name.Equals("Ian")).Select(ua => ua.terminal).ToArray();

    // If I take it one step further and Select the site, I end up with an array of 3 sites (only 2 exist)
    var v2 = v.Select(t => t.site).ToArray();

    // What I want is the allSites array but with the terminals filtered.
}

internal class Site
{
    public string SiteName { get; set; }
    public List<Terminal> Terminals { get; set; }
}

internal class Terminal
{
    public string TerminalName { get; set; }
    public Site site { get; set; }
    public List<UserAccess> AccessList { get; set; }
}

internal class UserAccess
{
    public User user { get; set; }
    public Terminal terminal { get; set; }
}

internal class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to provide a [mcve] of at least the classes involved.

Comment: Good advice @Enigmativity, I'll knock one up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like my brother-in-arms @DeclanMcD in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28691744), I had to resort to explicitly filtering the data.  I feel this solution might be a little cleaner, but I still don't like it:

```
// What I want is the allSites array but with the terminals filtered.
List<Site> toReturn = new List<Site>(allSites);
foreach (Site s in toReturn)
{
    // Look through every Terminal
    // And check if they have any UserAccess that would allow access.
    // If no access (!t.AccessList.Any), remove this Terminal.
    s.Terminals.RemoveAll(t => !t.AccessList.Any(
        a => a.user.Name.Equals("Ian")));
}

// Also if I want empty Sites removed:
toReturn.RemoveAll(s => !s.Terminals.Any());
```

The outer `foreach` could probably be LINQ-ified, but then I wouldn't be able to read it anymore.

Any better answer will get votes and appreciation.